# Remove empty (NA) elements from a list

Tags: r

how can I remove all elements of a list satisfying the following situation?

```
miRNA_annotation$EGOT[1]
[1] NA

miRNA_annotation$ELTD1[1]
[1] NA
```

thank you a lot

Best

```
dput(miRNA_annotation)
structure(list(AATF = NA_character_, NKIRAS2 = <S4 object of class structure("targetscanTarget", package = "targetscan.Hs.eg.db")>, 
    DDX52 = <S4 object of class structure("targetscanTarget", package = "targetscan.Hs.eg.db")>,.....,) Names = c("AATF",...., "ELTD1", "EGOT"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you mean something like this

```
x<-list(a=1, b=2, c=NA, d=3, e=NA)
x[sapply(x, function(z) !all(is.na(z)))]

# $a
# [1] 1
# 
# $b
# [1] 2
# 
# $d
# [1] 3
```

Here we use `sapply` to filter the list to only include elements that have at least one non-NA value.

Answer (score 3):

Or using @MrFlick's example

```
 Filter(Negate(is.na), x)
```

If it is to include at least one non-NA

```
 Filter(Negate(function(y) all(is.na(y)) ), x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could also use:

```
EGOTNA<-which(is.na(miRNA_annotation$EGOT))
miRNA_annotation <- miRNA_annotation[-EGOTNA,]
```